# Is this a pure imaginary number or real number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is $\dfrac{0}{2yi}$ a pure imaginary number or a real number?

I'm debating, $0$ is a real number but if you divide by $i$, it's imaginary.

Comment: isnt that number just $0$?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. This is a great help on here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/  Look what I did to your post!  Click edit and you can see the MathJax that does this.

Comment: You left out another possibility: when $y=0$, the expression is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You told us nothing about $y$ but, assuming that $y$ is a non-zero complex number, then $\dfrac0{2yi}=0$, which is both a real number and a pure imaginary number. It's actually the only complex number with both properties.

Answer (score 2):

If $y\neq 0$, in the complex plane, by definition, $0=0+0i$. Since the imaginary and real parts are 0, 0 is purely real and imaginary. However, it's also member of the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{0}{2yi}=0$$

which is an integer, a rational, a real and a complex number.

Notably it indicates the neutral element with respect to addition.

Comment: ...and the absorbing element under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Well, provided that $y \neq 0$, you are multiplying by $\frac{1}{2y}$.  (Of course, if $y = 0$ then it is undefined.)  So, I will talk of multiplication rather than division.  I am guessing that $y$ is intended to be real but that does not actually affect the answer.

A complex number is real if the imaginary component is zero.  Conversely, it is imaginary if the real component is zero. Most complex numbers e.g. $1 + i$ are neither. $0$ is special in that it is both.

Generally multiplying by $i$ will flip real numbers to imaginary and vice versa.  Since $0 \times i = 0$ multiplying by $i$ does change it, it goes from both to both.

Something a little like this occurs with the more familiar real numbers.  Multiplying by $-1$ flips positive and negative.  It leaves $0$ alone, so is $0$ positive or negative?  The usual answer is that $0$ is neither but considering it as both could work.  The [Bourbaki (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) school proposed this.  I found a reference thanks to posting a question here: [Bourbaki and zero (this site).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021166/bourbaki-and-zero/3021192?noredirect=1#comment6230173_3021192)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1112492)

Comment: I had intended to just add to the answers of others but I have expanded the answer to be self-sufficient.