# Bourbaki and zero

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

I had a memory that the Bourbaki school proposed that $0$ be considered both positive and negative rather than neither.  I cannot find any confirmation of this.  Can someone point me to one or am I dreaming?

[Nicolas Bourbaki (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [André Weil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Weil), [Number Theory for Beginners (1979)](https://books.google.it/books?id=NEHaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3) page 2 :

> A rational number is *positive* ($\ge 0$) or *negative* ($\le 0$); only $0$ is both.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't normally accept answers immediately but it is hard to see that a better one will come along.